# Is there is any way using which I can insert a list of result produced by select query from one table into another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

what actually I am trying to do is , I am fetching list of records from a employee table .

```
SELECT emp_id 
  FROM employee 
 WHERE login_date > p_date ; --p_date is a day start time-stamp
```

then inserting it into another table : `Members`

like members logged in today on time :

```
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 1..emp_count LOOP
     INSERT INTO team_member(user_id) VALUES (emp_id); 
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Is there is any better way to do that ...If anyone can suggest

Answer (score 1):

You just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into team_members (user_id)
    select emp_id
    from employee
    where login_date > p_date ;
```

Comment: But ont using the above query it is giving me an error saying :-ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row , as I am using few more values to insert in team_members table ... the complete query will be  :- insert into team_member (user_id ,last_updated_Byuser) VALUES (emp_id , TEST1);

Comment: @ASHUTOSHSHARMA . . . There is no subquery in this answer, so it cannot be generating that error.

Comment: Sir I am using like this                                                                                                  
    insert into team_member (user_id ,last_updated_Byuser) VALUES ( (select emp_id
    from employee
    where login_date > p_date ), TEST1);

Comment: Hi @ASHUTOSHSHARMA . Try `INSERT INTO team_member (user_id ,last_updated_Byuser) SELECT emp_id, 'TEST1' FROM employee WHERE login_date > p_date;` then.

Comment: @ASHUTOSHSHARMA . . . The code in your comment is not related to the question asked here.  This answers the question that was asked.